# How to get date timestamp of a symlink or directory using ansible?

Tags: ansible

Is there a way we can extract modification date/time of a symlink or directory using Ansible.
For example on my remote host in directory `/opt/tomcat/apps` I have this symlink `myapp -> /opt/tomcat/releases/Release1.20.0-01/myapp/webapp/`.

I know `ls -lrt` gives you the date and time but is there a way to get it using Ansible playbook?

`lrwxrwxrwx  1 tomcat tomcat   48 May 15 13:26 myapp -> /opt/tomcat/releases/Release1.20.0-01/myapp/webapp/`

I want to extract the date and time from this and store it in a variable in Ansible. Please let me know if someone can advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [stat](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/stat_module.html) module to get the details of file or directory and then fetch relevant information like `atime`, `ctime`, `time` etc.

Here is a sample:

```
- name: get file statistics
  stat:
    path: /path/to/link
  register: status

- debug:
    msg: "{{ status.stat.mtime }}"
```

---

Since `atime`, `ctime`, `mtime` properties return float you may like to convert them to date or string. To do that, you may create a small filter like [this](https://qiita.com/leechungkyu/items/de4dc3af1bbd800fb74d).

Comment: Perfect. why haven't i thought of it. I converted it using this - ```{{ '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S' | strftime(p.stat.ctime) }}"```

Comment: Yeah, that should do as well.